# Binding to ViewModel.SubClass.Property (sub-property)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

let's say i have a section on my screen where "current record" is edited.. so my view model has a class with all currently edited properties such as:

```
class Record { 
    public string Notes { get { return "Foo"; } set { _notes = value; Notify("Notes"); }
}
```

and we add this class to the view model:

```
class AdjustsmentViewModel {
    public Record CurrentRecord { get { return new Record(); }}
}
```

How can i bind to Notes property of CurrentRecord in my view? I tried this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentRecord.Notes, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" AcceptsReturn="True"  />
```

This is not working however. I also tried setting DataContext of surrounding StackPanel:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding CurrentRecord}">
```

After that, i tried in my TextBox {Binding Notes} and {Binding Path=Notes}, but none of these seem to work.

Perhaps above really should work and i am messing something elsewhere?

**Update**

This is happening in a user control. This user control has a separate view model, from it's parent window.

```
this.DataContext = UnityUtil.Resolve<AdjustmentsViewModel>();
```

Also i am seeing a binding error: *'Notes' property not found on 'object' ''MainViewModel'*

that view model is set on the main window.

to verify that i have the right ViewModel bound, i just added this property directly on the viewmodel:

```
public string Notes2 { get { return "Bar"; } }
```

and corresponding textblock in the view:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Notes2}" />
```

this works as expected.

**Great Success**

Thanks to Ryan, i was able to find the problem. It was not in the property itself, but the way CurrentRecord was being set. In my setter, i make a call to INotifyPropertyChange handler, but that had the old name of the property in it. So the view was not getting a CurrentRecord notification, so i guess Notes notification was not enough ..

in conclusion, this notation is correct: **{Binding Path=CurrentRecord.Notes}**

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: no errors. i just don't see the value (my default Foo string) in the textbox

Comment: What is your view...a window, a user control, a data template? How are you setting the datacontext of your view to your view model object?

Comment: One thing you're going to want to fix is that you need a "setter" for your Notes property if you want TwoWay binding.

Comment: Ryan, i updated my question with this info. also i do have a setter just didn't include in pseudo code above.. will fix

Comment: Have you verified that after your UnityUtil.Resolve method runs, that the UserControl's DataContext really does get set to an AdjustmentsViewModel?

Comment: yes. i just put a property directly on the viewmodel and bound to it no problem.. (updated my question with the code)

Comment: When your viewmodel is loaded, does CurrentRecord have a value or is it null and set later after some event, like selecting a record from a list?

Comment: initially it was set, and INotifyPropertyChanged called.. but now just tried hard coding the value: public string Notes3 { get { return "Notes3"; } }  and setting the binding to Notes3. still nothing..

Comment: I wasn't talking about the Notes property...I was talking about your CurrentRecord property. In your code above, you're returning a "new Record" right in your getter, but I'm assuming you're really returning a class field (e.g. get { return _currentRecord; }). Is this the case? And if so, when does _currentRecord get set?

Comment: Ryan, i think you're onto something. one min....

Comment: yep! so .. i explained in the question.. but basically i call Notify("PropertyName") in all my setters that need to notify.. (which than calls INotifyPropertyChanged handler..   but i changed the name of CurrentRecord w/out changing that string in the Notify(name) call.. Maybe there is a better pattern of doing this so that i can ensure such things never happen?   Thanks @Ryan!

Comment: Yeah, that's a drawback of using strings as the mechanism to notify a property has changed. I think some of the MVVM frameworks, e.g. PRISM, let you notify via the property itself (which in turn just uses some reflection I think). Glad you're all set.

Comment: First thing you need to do when debugging WPF binding problems is turn up debug messages for databinding: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MF8i5.png Next, re-run and check the output window and see what errors are there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The above should work, {Binding Path=CurrentRecord.Notes} is right. Can you check that your datacontext is set to your viewmodel?

Also check if your viewmodel implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

edit:
I just created a sample project to recreate this. No need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, it just works when the datacontext is set to the VM.

Comment: i have not tried this particular binding before actually.. but it still doesn't seem to work..

Comment: @SonicSoul what exactly does work...Your notes inside a record aren't showing up in your textbox or when you type in the textbox, they aren't going to your record's notes...or both? Are there any errors in your Output window...like a binding error?

Comment: both do not work. i default my string to Foo. that doesn't show up. if i type in some other value in the textbox and press a button to look at the debugger.. the property still has "Foo" in it, so it was not affected, or showed.. not seeing any relevant errors in the Output

Comment: Does the output window show a System.Windows.Data binding error?

Comment: yes. "'Notes' property not found on 'object' ''MainViewModel' "   Not sure why it is looking there.. that is the view model for the window.. where as i am in a user control with a different viewmodel set (and working, as my other properties bind fine)

Comment: How are you setting the DataContext for your user control. Are you setting it explicitly in XAML or the code-behind? Did you type MainViewModel instead of MyViewModel accidentally?

Comment: updated my question with that info, and corrected the names. tried to keep it simple for the question

Comment: Could you post a bit more of the usercontrol? A binding that works for example? The working binding obviously has a different datacontext than the textbox.

Comment: yes, i added a working binding, and added the code to my question. basically anything i put directly on the viewmodel works.

Comment: @SonicSoul: Just as a follow up: You could always use NotifyPropertyWeaver to automatically add the propertychanged handling to your code. No need to worry about wrong property names anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your CurrentRecord property is 1) being set and 2) notifying the UI layer that a change has occurred.