# Avoiding fatter view models in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism-4

I am working on a WPF application that follows an MVVM pattern. Inspite of moving the validation into services, I am ending up with a fat viewmodels that runs for several lines of code(in my case close to 1000 lines). 
I have added the interface for the viewmodel here. I got a few collections exposed as combo and based on the combo selection, I have to perform validation/invoke service/apply filtering to other combos

```
public interface ISampleViewModel         {
        ObservableCollection<InstrumentDto> Collection1 { get; set; }
        ObservableCollection<TenderViewConfigDetailViewModel> Collection2 { get; set; }
        ObservableCollection<TenderViewConfigDetailViewModel> Collection3 { get; set; }
        ObservableCollection<TenderViewConfigDetailViewModel> Collection4 { get; set; }
        ObservableCollection<TenderViewConfigDetailViewModel> Collection5 { get; set; }
        TenderViewConfigDetailViewModel SelectedViewConfigDetail { get; set; }
        int SelectedTenderViewIndex { get; set; }
        int SelectedInstrumentsViewIndex { get; set; }
        SortableCollection<TenderViewToInstrumentViewModel> CurrentInstruments { get; set; }
        TenderViewToInstrumentViewModel SelectedInstrumentForTenderView { get; set; }
        InstrumentDto SelectedInstrument { get; set; }
        bool IsAllInstrumentsFocused { get; set; }
        ICommand ApplyChangesCommand { get; }
        ICommand AddTenderPanelViewCommand { get; }
        ICommand DeleteTenderPanelViewCommand { get; }
        ICommand ModifyTenderViewVisiblityCommand { get; }
        ICommand AddInstrumentsToPanelViewCommand { get; }
        ICommand DeleteInstrumentsFromPanelViewCommand { get; }
        ICommand MoveUpTenderListViewCommand { get; }
        ICommand MoveDownTenderListViewCommand { get; }
        ICommand MoveUpInstrumentsCommand { get; }
        ICommand MoveDownInstrumentsCommand { get; }
        bool IsValidModel { get; }
        void PublishTenderViewConfigChanges(TenderViewConfigDetailViewModel viewModel,EventActionType actionType);
    }
```

The above set of functionality make my viewmodel bulkier. How can I avoid avoid it? I cant think of breaking the functionality into smaller controls as they are dependent? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Why are your viewmodels fat? Can you give an example? There's nothing wrong with a 1000 line viewmodel assuming that it addresses a simple concern. If you are covering 10 bases with a single viewmodel, it might be time to refactor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have stored in the `ViewModel` properties that can be isolated in separate classes, it is best to move them to a separate `Model`. Large number of properties pretty loads `ViewModel`, for each type of properties you should create your `Model`. Although on this occasion there is some debate, I believe there is nothing wrong if in the `ViewModel` will be links to several `Models`. On this subject you can see this answers:

[In MVVM, is every ViewModel coupled to just one Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085670/in-mvvm-is-every-viewmodel-coupled-to-just-one-model)

Example of using separate models:

**`Model`**

```
public class MainMenuModel : NotificationObject // Here also implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface
{
    private bool _buttonIsEnabled = true;

    public bool ButtonIsEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return _buttonIsEnabled;
        }

        set
        {
            _buttonIsEnabled = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonIsEnabled");
        }
    }     
}
```

**`ViewModel`**

```
public class MainMenuViewModel
{
    private MainMenuModel _mainMenuModel = null;

    public MainMenuModel MainMenuModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _mainMenuModel;
        }

        set
        {
            _mainMenuModel = value;
        }
    }

    ...

    public MainMenuViewModel() 
    {
        MainMenuModel = new MainMenuModel();
    }
}
```

**`View`**

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=MainMenuModel.ButtonIsEnabled}" ... />
```

The only thing that can be left on the side of the `ViewModel`, it Commands and `IDataErrorInfo` interface implementation, although implementation of `IDataErrorInfo` can also be moved to the side of the `Model`.

Also, if the implementation of Command takes a lot of space, you can create separate function / procedure that can be called such `Helper` and place in suitable class. Next, in Command did not write the whole implementation, it's necessary refer to this method.

For example:

```
private ICommand _findCommand = null;

public ICommand FindCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_findCommand == null)
        {
            _findCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.Find(), null);
        }

        return _findCommand;
    }
}

private void Find()
{
    // Here instead of writing large code, 
    // moving find logic to separate static class

    SomeHelper.FindPerson(MainModel.SearchName);
}
```

Therefore Command in this case is a wrapper for a call method in `ViewModel`.

Comment: Thanks for the Solution. You mean to say move the functionality into smaller viewmodels and expose it in the main/parent viewmodel. Here, I can see a model implementing a NotificationObject which is not ideal. Usually, the notifications should be kept at viewmodel instead of model

Comment: @Hunter: `I can see a model implementing a NotificationObject which is not ideal.` - each chooses where to implement it, it is not very important. I suggest to move the properties in the separate Model, and do not write them all in `ViewModel`. Much easier to refer a single object, than ten properties. I also added some thoughts about commands, see my edit.

Comment: are models supposed to be POCO. Will it be an issue if we decide to use the same models in services?

Comment: @Hunter: Yes, the Model can be POCO. I think the Model is one of the most abstract parts in `MVVM`, and if this is correct abstraction defined, I think problems do not happen in the use of these models in the services.