# How to access ObservableCollection nested in view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a simple single window WPF app using MVVM. XAML is binded to my MainViewModel.cs class, which contains an ObservableCollection Sites. Now SiteModel class has a property named Owners, which contains second ObservableCollection companies.

I need to bind my companies property to a ComboBox in my XAML. ComboBox is nested in DataGrid. Situation is described below.

```
<DataGrid Name="UxSiteGrid" DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Sites, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
              Margin="5,5,5,0" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding VseId}" Header="Vse ID"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IMO}" Header="IMO"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SiteType}" ItemsSource="{local:EnumValues rdsConfigConnector:SiteType}" Header="Site type"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TimePeriod}" Header="Fetching period"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Latitude}" Header="Latitude"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Longitude}" Header="Longitude"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OffsetLatitude}" Header="Offset latitude"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OffsetLongitude}" Header="Offset longitude"/>


            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Site Owners">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Owners.companies}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data-context inside your `DataTemplate` should already be your site so `{Binding Owners.companies}` should work (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619612/binding-to-viewmodel-subclass-property-sub-property)).
Be aware that data-binding is case-sensitive => may it shoudl be `{Binding Owners.Companies}`?

If that all is correct: Did you get a "binding error" in the output window?

Comment: Yes you are right about the case-sensitivity, it should be withe uppercas C. Still I got this error:
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Owners' property not found on 'object' ''MainViewModel' (HashCode=11497055)'. BindingExpression:Path=Owners.companies; DataItem='MainViewModel' (HashCode=11497055); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Seems like data-context is on MainViewModel here

Comment: Hm, thats strange - I just checked in my project and there the `DataTemplate` is directly binding to my single item from my `ItemsSource`. Can you try creating a small test-app to just test that single binding feature?

Comment: Works fine in new project. I actually managed to fix it in my current app as well, seems like the lower case was a cause of trouble in the end. I feel a bit stupid right now :))